# How to get "INSTALLED" property in Custom Action DLL (MSI/Wix)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, wix, windows-installer

In my custom DLL I need to check if product is being installed or uninstalled, and hence need to get value of `"INSTALLED"` property (just like in WiX script). Here is what I am doing in C++ DLL:

```
WCHAR propValue[MAX_PATH];
DWORD propValLen = MAX_PATH;
// MSIHANDLE msiHandle; 
MsiGetProperty(msiHandle, L"INSTALLED", propValue, &propValLen);
propValue[propValLen] = 0;
```

But the outcome is always an empty string (for both installation and uninstallation)! How check if product is being installed or uninstalled?

Comment: How is this custom action scheduled? (See [Obtaining Context Information for Deferred Execution Custom Actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370543) for why I'm asking.)

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem I just figured out. Some actions are immediate and some are deferred!

Comment: @MichaelUrman, Can you please add your input as answer? It will be useful for others. This information isn't clearly available anywhere.

Comment: http://blog.iswix.com/2011/10/beam-me-up-using-json-to-serialize.html

Comment: @Ajay this article written in 2001 is on my "required reading" list and goes into great detail all the things related to this question.  http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/

Comment: Funny story, I had that article pinned to my cube and I read it every day not understanding it at first.  The reason was InstallShield < v12 ignored all this so it wasn't until InstallShield 12 beta in 2006 that it all actually made sense.

Comment: @Ajay, I can add my input as an answer when the question has enough information to justify it. As is, it leverages psychic debugging skills, so it remains a guess (and thus a comment). (OTOH, once the question has enough information, it's probably a duplicate of one of the many CustomActionData questions.) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property name is case-sensitive, it is "Installed": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369297(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I verified. For the custom DLL, it is case sensitive. For the MSI/Wix, it is not. It it possible to do case-insensitive lookup using MSI functions ?

Comment: @Ajay AFAIK there is no case-insensitive query. Just write code everywhere with correct case and problem solved.

Comment: Actually your answer is not correct. MSI properties are case insensitive. It's just the execution context. All properties are visible in 'immediate' custom action handlers, but none of the properties are visible in 'deffered' handlers. I just noted that DLL itself is loaded/unloaded multiple times, hence unable to store the property values in global variables!

Comment: @Ajay, I've been using MSI for 18 years.  MSI properties are most certainly case sensitive.  There are three catagories. Private, Public and Secure.  Private contain lower case, Public contain only upper case and Secure are public properties that are also listed in the SecureCustomPublicProperties property.  There is no such thing as a case insensitive property in MSI and any tool that creates MSI.